# Is it possible to change user agent in Crosswalk Android/Tizen-Apps?

Tags: android, html, tizen

I am developing an android/tizen app using crosswalk project. Now i need to change the user agent to view page in desktop version.
Is it possible to change user agent and how?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet:

```
XWalkView mXWalkView;
mXWalkView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Your User Agent");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code is doing and how it works, so that newbies like the OP will be able to learn from the answer.

Comment: Didn't solve my actual problem, but the server recognizes the new user-agent.
Thank You! :)

Answer (score 5):

I used reflection to solve this problem until this API goes public again in [Crosswalk 12](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-12-beta.html). This works in Crosswalk 9.38.208.10.

```
private void setWebViewUserAgent(XWalkView webView, String userAgent)
{
    try
    {
        Method ___getBridge = XWalkView.class.getDeclaredMethod("getBridge");
        ___getBridge.setAccessible(true);
        XWalkViewBridge xWalkViewBridge = null;
        xWalkViewBridge = (XWalkViewBridge)___getBridge.invoke(webView);
        XWalkSettings xWalkSettings = xWalkViewBridge.getSettings();
        xWalkSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        // Could not set user agent
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, It seems `getSettings` is no longer available. Are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

In documentation is nothing bout it. Propably only way is use setResourceClient and WebResourceResponse to change user agent.
Example use:

```
setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(this) {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptLoadRequest(XWalkView view, String url) {
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
            c.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "test user agent");
            return new WebResourceResponse(null, "utf-8", c.getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.shouldInterceptLoadRequest(view, url);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, but it slows down the performance and loading times. It is a very interesting answer, I've learned a lot.
Thank You!

Comment: The solution may be use this only for first url (skil for loading other resources, images etc)

Answer (score 1):

The new API to set user agent is in draft and will be released in Crosswalk-12, about the end of January next year.

It will be like:
xwalkView.setUserAgentString(newUserAgentString);

Comment: Source: https://www.mail-archive.com/crosswalk-help@lists.crosswalk-project.org/msg00634.html

Answer (score 0):

**This is for web-apps where you can alter JS-Files.:**

I use this workaround, it works as well with Crosswalk 9.

```
xview.addJavascriptInterface(new Object(){
            @JavascriptInterface
            public String getNewUserAgent(){
                return "My User Agent";
            }
        }, "NativeInterface");
```

And in my web-app i just call:

```
navigator.ua = NativeInterface.getNewUserAgent();
```

Comment: Thank You. Until now I use Crosswalk 8, but that is an interesting info!